# Url redirection is not working properly if we open the some product url

Tags: product, magento-2.2.5

I have a product URL

> http://dev.com/abcd/xyz.html

(This is the English store URL). I have a different URL for different stores. For the above product, I have different URL in Deutsch store.

> http://dev.com/abcd/pqr.html

So if I open the English store URL for the first time it will redirect correctly. if I switch the store from English to Deutsch and close the browser, and again enter English store URL it will not redirect correctly it is going to 404. (English URL is not converting to Deutsch).How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that your site is based on magento 2 as you tag magento 2.2.5

You have to reindex for getting right product.
you can use following command for it

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Generally there is no need to flush the cache, but for safe side run

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Best regards,
Krunal Pathak

Answer (score 0):

Magento always redirect on the basis of redirection url's. once you create any new store,website or product so automatically it generate its redirection url's but in your case it is generating any url so you have to run:

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
```

This indexing regenerate the url's of your product and it will work.

if you find this answer helpful please mark it as solution or upvote thanks.

Comment: Hi Shubham, if I am in the URL http://dev.com/abcd/xyz.html and switch the store to Deutsch it will redirect correctly to http://dev.com/abcd/pqr.html.My question is if I send the URL  http://dev.com/abcd/xyz.html to you it will open for you.if you change the store from English to Deutsch and close the browser, then if you enter the URL  http://dev.com/abcd/xyz.html it will go to 404.(it will search the English store URL in Deutsche store so it is redirecting to 404.)

Comment: did you create a new store recently?